# Spring boot - @Validated makes my variable annotated with @Value null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a controller that I try to test and have some issues.

The question is that `@Validated` annotation permits me to validate a regex that I have in `@PathVariable` and `@Value` annotation permits me to get a list of strings from a config file.

When I run tests about this controller, my variable `whitelist` appears `null`, but if I remove `@Validated` annotation from the controller, the `whitelist` variable has expected values.

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class MyController {

    @Value("${myProject.whitelist:}")
    public String[] whitelist;

    @PostMapping(value = "/myProject/{serial}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public GenericPostResponse createFoo(
        @Valid @Pattern(regexp = SERIAL_VALIDATION_REGEX) @PathVariable String serial){
        (...)
    }


    (...)

}
```

I would love to know, why `@Validated` annotation transforms my variables annotated with `@Value` into `null`.

Comment: It doesn't. They are `null` in the proxy generated for `@Validated` they aren't in the actual object. When you remove `@Validated` the proxy isn't created and they don't appear `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, there is any way to have both annotations and test the controller with the values from the whitelist variable with no nulls?

Comment: The test should just work, if it doesn't you are doing something weird in your test **or** the code shown here isn't the code of your actual project.

Comment: I use @Autowired myController in my tests, should I use a new instance?

Comment: As stated it will be `null` on the proxy not on the actual instance. So what is the actual issue you have? You see `null` in the debugger (that is as expected) or is your test failing?

Comment: both, I see the null in the debugger and my test fails with NoSuchFieldException because I try to getDeclaredField("whitelist") of that controller. My goal is to put a string to that "@Value variable for a test, but only get achieved that without the "@Validated attribute that is also needed in my code.

Comment: Which is exactly what I explained. It is null on the proxy. If you get the field you get it on the proxy not the real object, so it will be null. Basically your test is wrong.

Comment: And there is some way to get the object itself in my test? I thought that '@RestController creates a bean of that Object and with '@Autowired we get that specific instance of the object.
Sorry for so many questions

Comment: `@RestController` doesn't do anything, it is just metadata. Nonetheless it leads to an instance, which is than proxied due to `@Validated`. This proxied instance is the instance that will be used for injection. But as mentioned your test is flawed, if you want the underlying instance use `AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject` to get the unproxied instance on which you can use `ReflectionTestUtils.getField` to obtain the value. However you must question yourself do you really want to test this, you are basically testing Spring with this and not your own code.